# Recursion function not working properly

Tags: python, recursion

I'm having quite a hard time figuring out what's going wrong here:

```
class iterate():
    def __init__(self):
        self.length=1
    def iterated(self, n):
        if n==1:
            return self.length
        elif n%2==0:
            self.length+=1
            self.iterated(n/2)
        elif n!=1:
            self.length+=1
            self.iterated(3*n+1)
```

For example,

```
x=iterate()
x.iterated(5)
```

outputs `None`.  It should output 6 because the length would look like this:
5 --> 16 --> 8 --> 4 --> 2 --> 1

After doing some debugging, I see that the `self.length` is returned properly but something goes wrong in the recursion.  I'm not really sure.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm curious, what version of Python are you using? I usually use Python 2.6 and init needs to be declared as __init__. But this clearly runs for you, so I'm wondering what version of Python allows this

Comment: @inspectorG4dget - The provided source code had double underscores around the `init`, but they were originally removed by the formatting and not displayed (which I'm guessing is what also happened to your comment). I've fixed the formatting for the question now.

Comment: @ire_and_curses: So it seems. Looks like the double underscore is the text are formatting for bold!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the two `elif` blocks, you don't return a value after making the recursive call. You need a `return` before the recursive calls to `iterated` (e.g. `return self.iterated(n/2)`). If you don't explicitly `return`, the function will return `None`.

That will fix this issue, but there is a way to make your code simpler: You don't actually need the member `length`. Instead, you can add 1 to the result of the recursive call:

```
def iterated(n):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    elif n%2==0:
        return 1 + iterated(n/2)
    else:
        return 1 + iterated(3*n+1)

print(iterated(5))
```

This doesn't need to be in a class, since there is no need for any members.

Comment: Didn't you rewrite it into a stack-unsafe version?

Comment: @Andronicus What do you mean by "stack-unsafe"? If you mean not tail-recursive, then Python doesn't have tail recursion optimization so it doesn't matter.

Comment: OP's implementation is stack-safe because it accumulates the result in `length` variable. It doesn't need to keep the stack of execution. Your implementation doesn't use the accumulator an every step needs to be kept on stack. I'm not fluent in python, maybe it optimizes it on the fly.

Comment: @Andronicus As I said in my previous comment, this is not relevant in Python.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the return statements:

```
class iterate():
    def init(self):
        self.length=1
    def iterated(self, n):
        if n==1:
            return self.length
        elif n%2==0:
            self.length+=1
            **return** self.iterated(n/2)
        elif n!=1:
            self.length+=1
            **return** self.iterated(3*n+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only returning a value from the deepest level of recursion, then ignoring it on the second-deepest level.

All of the `self.iterated(...)` lines should read `return self.iterated(...)`

Answer (score 2):

You should finish each elif branch with `return self.iterated(...)` rather than just `self.iterated(...)`

Comment: THANK YOU this helped me! It was so weird my function was literally ignoring the self.function_call() in an if statement, it printed both statements before and after that line! How bizarre...
Using return helped to finally get it to work like it should.