# Why my code return a Type error of unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'

Tags: python, algorithm

I wang to reserve a char list by recursion in python, but I get a type error in the last step, I don't know why this happened. I will appreciate you

```py
def reverseString(s):
    if len(s) ==1:
        s
    else:
        reverseString(s[1:])+list(s[0])
```

input like `['a','b','c','d']`,

expected output `['d','c','b','a']`

there is a *type error*:

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'

Comment: You do not return anything in `reversedString`.

Comment: Related and possibly a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946631/recursion-function-not-working-properly/2946647#2946647

Comment: Yep, no `return`. You might have found this yourself if you had extracted the required (!) [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return something in your function. If you do not return something explicitly, Python will implicitly return `None`.

It might be better to check if the string has a length that is zero (so the empty string), such that your function can reverse an empty string as well:

```
def reverseString(s):
    if not s:
        return s
    else:
        return reverseString(s[1:])+s[0]
```

For example:

```
>>> reverseString('foobar')
'raboof'
```

Using recursion, especially *linear* recursion is not a good idea here, since the call stack grows with the length of the string, and thus for not so small strings, you will get a stackoverflow.

You can make use of the `reversed(..)` iterator of a string, and thus return the reversed string with:

```
>>> ''.join(reversed('foobar'))
'raboof'
```

this is especially useful if you want to iterate over the string in reverse, without constructing one (for example when processing the individual characters in reverse).

or through slicing, as [@Austin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739239/why-my-code-return-a-type-error-of-unsupported-operand-types-for-nonetype/57739251?noredirect=1#comment101917704_57739251) says:

```
>>> 'foobar'[::-1]
'raboof'
```

Comment: Or easier: `'foobar'[::-1]`.

Comment: @Austin: yes, if one however wants to iterate over a (significantly) long string, it might be better to use reversed, since that does not make a copy, but added it.