# recursion function do not return value

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a function that takes an integer and a string(1234,"3")
the function should find if the integer contain the value of the string via recursion.
so I wrote the following code:

```
def has_digit_recursion(num,string):
    num_s = str(num)
    if num_s[-1] == string:
        return True
        
    num //=10
    has_digit_recursion(num, string)
```

the recursion seems to work but I don't get the return value. instead I get

```
None
```

help will be appreciated.

Comment: `return has_digit_recursion(num, string)` This happens alot. People forget to return the result of the recursive call.

Comment: I'm going to guess you didn't bother trying to use a debugger.

Comment: Also, you need to `return False` when it is not found.

Comment: duplicate of  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946631/recursion-function-not-working-properly?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to add a return when calling the function recursively.
Plus you need to verify what the variable num is at every recursion step, otherwise the recursion won't stop.

Here is the new code :

```py
def has_digit_recursion(num,string):
    num_s = str(num)
    if num_s[-1] == string:
        return True
        
    num //= 10
    if num == 0:
        return False
    return has_digit_recursion(num, string)

print(has_digit_recursion(1234, "0"))
print(has_digit_recursion(1234, "3"))
>>> False
>>> True
```